# Why is the @objc tag needed to use a selector?

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to use a selector to see if a certain protocol can perform an action. When I try it like this:

```
protocol Test {
    func hello()
    func goodBye(a: String)
}

class Tester: NSObject, Test {        
    override init() {}
    func hello() { }        
    func goodBye(a: String) { }
}

let a: Test = Tester()

let result = a.responds(to: Selector("goodByeWithA:"))
```

In this case, `result` evaluates to `false`.

But if I add the `@objc` tag to the protocol, it evaluates as `true`.

```
@objc protocol Test {
    func hello()
    func goodBye(a: String)
}
```

Why is this?

On a side note, I know that it is now recommended to use the `#selector` syntax and to move away from using strings, but for various reasons, I have to use a string in this case.

EDIT: This only started happening once I migrated my project to Swift 4.2

Comment: Unrelated! In `Swift`, `Types` always start with Upper case letter and `value` start with lowercase.

Comment: @Kamran this was just quick test code written in a playground

Comment: @DavidPilkington Yet that "quick test code" ended up on the internet for 87 people to see!

Comment: @Alexander sorry, I'm not seeing your point?

Comment: @DavidPilkington Although fully following convention to a T (e.g. long expressive variable names that meet the guidelines) doesn't make sense in a quick/dirty playground, there's some conventions that are "low hanging fruit" that I think are best following. The distinction between `UpperCamelCase` for types and `lowerCamelCase` for values is a pretty simple one that's just as quick to follow as it is to not, so I'd suggest always doing it. You never know when your quick/dirty code accidentally  ends up copied into prod code, stack overflow question, etc. unedited.

Comment: @DavidPilkington Unrelated: I love your avatar! It's sleek.

Answer (score 1):

By default Swift generates code that is only available to other Swift code, but if you need to interact with the Objective-C runtime – all of UIKit, for example – you need to tell Swift what to do.

That’s where the @objc attribute comes in: when you apply it to a class or method it instructs Swift to make those things available to Objective-C as well as Swift code. So, any time you want to call a method from a UIBarButtonItem or a Timer, you’ll need to mark that method using @objc so it’s exposed – both of those, and many others, are Objective-C code.

Don’t worry: if you forget to add @objc when it’s needed, your code simply won’t compile – it’s not something you can forget by accident and introduce a bug.

Comment: I understand what the attribute does, just in this case I am interested in what aspects of objective-c its needs as this only happened when I updated my project to swift 4.2

Comment: In Swift 4, such automatic objc inference is deprecated because it is costly to generate all those Objective-C entry points. When "Swift 3 objc Inference" setting is set to "On", it allows the old code to work. However, it will show deprecation warnings that need to be addressed. It is recommended to "fix" these warnings and switch the setting to "Default", which is the default for new Swift projects.

Comment: I think you should talk about selector-based dispatch, and how it differs from what Swift usually does.