# unrecognized selector sent to instance in swift 4.2

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm stuck with this problem since yesterday and I can't find any solution.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBAction func cameraButton(_ sender: Any) {

        cameraResultDisplay.text = "Camera Button Pressed!"

    }

    @IBOutlet weak var cameraResultDisplay: UILabel!

    func processTimer() {
        print("A second has passed!")
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        var timer = Timer()

        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: Selector("processTimer"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)        

    }
}
```

No matter what I do it still throws this error and this screen is shown out of nowhere:

```
http://prntscr.com/n1wmcl
```

And this is the full error log:

```
2019-03-23 21:42:52.788044+0530 Menu Bars[37292:1510342] -[Menu_Bars.ViewController processTimer]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fa185607fe0
2019-03-23 21:42:52.790421+0530 Menu Bars[37292:1510342] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Menu_Bars.ViewController processTimer]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fa185607fe0'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ff2f1bb __exceptionPreprocess + 331
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010f4cd735 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ff4df44 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 132
    3   UIKitCore                           0x00000001138a9b4a -[UIResponder doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 287
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ff33ed6 ___forwarding___ + 1446
    5   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ff35da8 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    6   Foundation                          0x000000010ef70881 __NSFireTimer + 83
    7   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010fe94f34 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 20
    8   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010fe94b32 __CFRunLoopDoTimer + 1026
    9   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010fe9439a __CFRunLoopDoTimers + 266
    10  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010fe8ea1c __CFRunLoopRun + 2252
    11  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010fe8de11 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 625
    12  GraphicsServices                    0x000000011900c1dd GSEventRunModal + 62
    13  UIKitCore                           0x000000011387b81d UIApplicationMain + 140
    14  Menu Bars                           0x000000010eba59d7 main + 71
    15  libdyld.dylib                       0x0000000112388575 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

I'm following an online course from Udemy and I wrote exactly the same code as the guy in the course writes. I tried a few things but I think I did some stupid things that's why it didn't work. Now I'm stuck with this problem from 2 days and it is giving me headache and there is no one to help me out with this problem.

Please help me with this thanks.

Comment: #selector(processTimer) is enough. you do not need to add "@objc" before processTimer because you are calling the function from swift only and function is defined in swift as well. "@objc" is needed when you need to make the swift function available to Objective C.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `@objc` to the definition of your function in order to use it with selector:

```
@objc func processTimer() {
    print("A second has passed!")
}
```

But using selector this way is not recommended, instead do the following:

Replace the line of code, where you schedule your timer with following:

```
timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(processTimer), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

When you pass a function as selector parameter you need to use the following syntax:

```
selector: #selector(functionName)
```

Comment: It doesnt work at all. It throws the error immediately when I write what I suggested.

Comment: Adding @objc to the function name worked. But why did it worked for the guy in the course? What is it ? Something to do with Objective C? If yes then what can we write in Swift to remove this error?

Comment: Are you sure the guy didn't add @objc to the function declaration? Also check the following answer it might be useful for you to understand why we need `@objc` -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/52988763/8447312

Comment: Yes Im sure and here is the screenshot from the course video: http://prntscr.com/n1wygc

Comment: Hmm this course is from 2016, not sure but maybe things have changed since then? I started iOS programming around the end of 2017.

Comment: BTW I didnt had to replace the code for timer. I only had to ad that @obj to the function and it worked.

Comment: I know but you must have warning with your implementation, its better to update your code with the one I provided. Also I would recommend you to proceed with a newer course.

Comment: @LaraSenchina Its because Swift changed, and you now have to **explicitly** state if something is `@objc`. This changed in Swift 3 I believe.

Comment: @George_E It changed in Swift 4. See https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0160-objc-inference.md